# Google Sheets copy certain fields to new sheet if record does not exist

Tags: google-sheets, copy, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to automate a process of adding records from sheet 1 to sheet 2 if the record does not already exist in sheet 2.

Sheet 1 has 20 columns however I only need columns A, D, E & F copied over to sheet 2

Column A is a membership number and this is the field I would want to use to validate if the record already exists or not in sheet 2 to initiate the copying.

I have very limited coding skills so I am looking for assistance from this awesome community.

Sheet1

```
+------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+
| ID   | Date     | Time  | Sal. | First Name | Last Name |
+------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+
| 1234 | 05/12/19 | 16:00 | Mr.  | John       | Doe       |
| 0001 | 05/12/19 | 17:00 | Mrs. | Jennifer   | Lawrence  |
| 1234 | 05/13/19 | 16:00 | Mr.  | John       | Doe       |
| 1233 | 05/13/19 | 16:00 | Mr.  | Johnny     | Deep      |
+------+----------+-------+------+------------+-----------+
```

Sheet2

```
+------+------+------------+-----------+
|  ID  | Sal. | First Name | Last Name |
+------+------+------------+-----------+
| 1234 | Mr.  | John       | Doe       |
| 0001 | Mrs. | Jennifer   | Lawrence  |
| 1233 | Mr.  | Johnny     | Deep      |
+------+------+------------+-----------+
```

Here is the code I have tried.  It only copies over the first column. How do I get it to copy columns 4, 5 & 6 as well?

```
function copy_Guest_info() {
  var spreadsheet, sheet, sheet2, endrow, 
endcol,endrow2,endcol2,data,data2,resultArray,n,l,l2,p,doesNotExist,
  sheetOneValue, numberOfMissingValues, innerArray,i,thisValue;

  spreadsheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1L3XjJvgruB_JNZWd2Vo2Tz32cc3quzhlIjSaPkOvV10');

  sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Reservations");
  sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("LCAH Guest Profile");

  endrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  endcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  endrow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
  endcol2 = sheet2.getLastColumn();

  data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, endrow, 1).getValues();
  //getRange(start row, start column, number of Rows, number of Columns)
  data2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 1, endrow2, 1).getValues();
  data2 = data2.toString().split(","); //Flatten the 2D array to one D

  resultArray = [];
  innerArray = [];
  l = data.length;
  l2 = data2.length;

  for (n=0;n<l;n+=1) {
    sheetOneValue = data[n][0];
    innerArray = []; //Reset

    for (p=0;p<l2;p+=1) {
      doesNotExist = data2.indexOf(sheetOneValue) === -1;//If the value is 
NOT found, indexOf returns -1  
      if (!doesNotExist) break; //If it exists in the list, no need to go 
any further
      if (doesNotExist) {//If the value in the cell from data one does NOT 
exist in data two, add it to the array

        innerArray.push(sheetOneValue)
        resultArray.push(innerArray);
        Logger.log('sheetOneValue: ' + sheetOneValue);
        break ;
      };
    };
  };

  endrow2 = 0;
  for (i=0;i<l;i+=1) {
    thisValue = data2[i];
    if (thisValue==="" || thisValue=== undefined) {//There is nothing in 
this cell
      continue;
    };
    endrow2+=1;
  };
  //Append the data in the array to the bottom of the data two list
  sheet2.getRange(endrow2+1, 1,resultArray.length,1).setValues(resultArray);

  Logger.log(resultArray);  
};
```

Comment: Hi there. Ideally you will need to show examples of the sheets in question and anything you've done to resolve this initially. People are willing to help you out on here, but we do need to see that you've made an effort before asking.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I will be perfectly honest...I have close to zero coding skills.  I have used other people's code for years for other excel macros and fumbled my way through modifying and trial and error until I figured out the nessicary changes need to the code to make it work for my needs. The trouble I am having is I have been able to find code on here that I have been able to get to work to copy only a single column but cant figure out what I would need to do to copy a select number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this simple formula in Sheet2:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:F); "select A,D,E,F"; 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Player0. The problem with this is if a line is removed from sheet1 which will be the case in my application then using QUERRY will also cause the data to be removed from sheet2 and I need that information to remain.

Comment: @CLHConcierge, in that case, you will need a script which will periodically archive your sheet1 into sheet2